# Need suggestions for a Sigle Board Linux Computer?

Tags: linux, embedded

I need suggestions for a single board computer, with these requirements:

- Runs linux
- Wifi
- (I/O module?)

Does not need much computing power. I'm using it for applications like twittering when the coffee at the office is ready etc. I'd like it to run linux, for easy scripting and a full network stack. (preferably pre-installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the list of [motherboards that run Linux](http://opencircuits.com/Motherboards_that_run_Linux)?

Comment: That list is exactly what i needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Gumstix](http://roboticsprimer.sourceforge.net/workbook/Howto:_Gumstix_and_Wifi_Setup) or [Marvell SheevaPlug](http://www.engadget.com/2010/01/05/marvell-plug-computer-3-0-packs-in-wifi-bluetooth-and-2ghz-arma/).