# Using an Ettus USRP on an embedded system

Tags: embedded

If I want to port all of the USRP driver library (UHD) to an embedded system where size matters. How difficult is that going to be?

The USRP driver is written in C++ with several library dependencies. How difficult is it to port a complex C++ program onto an embedded system ?

Answer (score 2):

The Universal Software Radio Peripheral (USRP) is a high-speed USB-based board for making software radios.

The GNU Radio software is designed to run on a PC connected to the USRP or some other radio hardware.

If your embedded system is running any one of:

- Linux
- Mac OS X
- BSD
- Windows

then it should be pretty simple to get the GNU Radio software running on the embedded system.
Otherwise, it would be pretty difficult -- perhaps it would be simpler to change the hardware to some
[single-board Linux computer](https://superuser.com/questions/137759/need-suggestions-for-a-sigle-board-linux-computer/182958)
rather than port the software to an embedded computer that does not support any of the above OSes.